# change mobile screen orientation with js

Tags: javascript, html, css

on my web page I have a button which opens a video on full screen. when it happens I need to automatically change and lock screen orientation (landscape). is it possible to do and if it is how can I do it? I need it to work both on android and iOS as well.

Comment: Sounds like the JavaScript Screen Orientation API (mdn web docs) is what you're looking for, specifically ```window.screen.orientation.lock(orientation: string)```.

Comment: @TARN4T1ON thanks. i tried it, but it doesn't work on safari, iphone.

Comment: I did overlook something, namely the Safari support, which starts at version 16.4, released 2023-03-27, for both macOS and iOS, so, depending on what version you tested it on, that's probably why. Apparently the (non-standard and deprecated) Window.orientation is a thing on iOS Safari since version 3, though (mdn web docs once again). Not on macOS Safari, but I guess that makes some sense. You might have some luck with that. You'd also need to do some polyfill to support both Android and iOS.